# How to rotate a square UIImage relative to it's one corner?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, transform, rotation

I want rotate a square UIImage relative to one of it's corner, for example, it's top left corner, how can I do it in a simple way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating a hand of a clock. (Rotation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769237/animating-a-hand-of-a-clock-rotation)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open source project: [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink), you will want to take a look at the Anchor Point Animation example. It will show you how to animate a box at each corner.